# Selenium send_keys complexity

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have 5 python files which are all the same. They do a very simple operation which is to log into some specific account and to write bunch of text. 
Every text has around 80 characters and i need to wait 1 second in between sending one character. Upon opening all Chromes, i minimize them so they don't pull a lot of CPU usage. After i start 1 chrome, sendkeys work completely fine. I get 1 character per second but after i start more chromes, this operation gets really slow. 
It seems like context switching in between threads is very slow. I don't understand what is the reason behind this. It sometimes takes around 2 minutes to write 40 character text but after i maximize chrome, that particular thread starts to behave normal and it works completely fine then.

```
 for j in range(len(firstPART)):
       element.send_keys(firstPART[j])
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Just to simplify your code you can iterate over the string instead of selecting each character by index: `for char in firstPART: element.send_keys(char)`